# How to cast the generator into the list in Owlready2

Tags: python, owlready

I have been trying to store the all classes and belongings with owlready2. Altough I convert the generators into the list, I am still getting the same ouput.

```
from owlready2 import *

onto = get_ontology("C:\\Users\\Kronos\\Desktop\\Ontology\\f3.owx").load()

class main():
    all_class= list(onto.classes())
    print(all_class)
```

Output goes on like this:

```
C:\Users\Kronos\Desktop\Ontology\f3.owx.Address, C:\Users\Kronos\Desktop\Ontology\f3.owx.BabyCare, ...
```

Answer (score 0):

For now, I'm storing it by brute force by taking the (.)dot after point.

`all_class = onto.classes()`

`class_names = [cls._name.split('.')[-1] for cls in all_class]`